# Flatten JSON data in Rails when using :include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, curl

I've added an "Advance Search" to my app using the "[#111 Advanced Search Form (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised)" tutorial and have created an API for it too. Everything works fine, but now I am trying to show the JSON data.

This is the cURL command:

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X 
GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/searches/129
```

And this is the results of the Curl command (Please note the brackets[ ], therefore this is an array of hashes.):

```
[{"id":4,"state_id":5,"name":"School Liason Officer","created_at":"2014-10-16T03:13:00.000Z",
"updated_at":"2014-10-16T03:13:00.000Z","state":{"name":"California"}}]
```

But I would like to change the JSON Results so that the state name is flattened with the JSON data somehow.

Does anyone know how I can do this, or if it's even possible to flatten the data?

This is an example of what I'd like:

```
[{"id":4,"state":"California","name":"School Liason Officer","created_at":"2014-10-16T03:13:00.000Z",
"updated_at":"2014-10-16T03:13:00.000Z"}]
```

Model:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :district_resources

end

class DistrictResource < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state

end

class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

  def district_resources
    @district_resources ||= find_district_resources
  end

  def find_district_resources
    district_resources = DistrictResource.order(:name)
    district_resources = district_resources.where(state_id: state_id) if state_id.present?
    district_resources
  end

end
```

API Controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SearchesController < ApplicationController

      respond_to :json

      def show
        @search = Search.find(params[:id])
        @searches = []
        (@searches << @search.district_resources).flatten!

        json = @searches.to_json

        def flatten_hash(h)
          new_hash = {}

          ###I get an error here undefined method `each_pair' for Array
          h.each_pair do |key, val|
            if val.is_a?(Hash)
              new_hash[key] = val.values.join(',')
            else
              new_hash[key] = val
            end
          end
          new_hash
        end

        flattened_hash = flatten_hash(JSON.parse(json))
        flattened_hash.delete("state_id")

        respond_to do |format|

          ###How can i merge the state name with the json results
          format.json { render :json => flattened_hash.to_json(:include => [:state => {:only => [:name]}] )}
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

ERROR

```
undefined method `each_pair' for #<Array:0x007f8d727b5168>
```

Comment: If you don't want to mess with too much post-processing, you could craft the SQL query to include  "... district_resources.state AS 'state'....." Not sure how you would do that but it's an approach. So rather than just return the state_id, have it look up the state and give it the key of "state".

Comment: The Rails syntax for "AS" is: `SomeTable.select("foo as bar").first` . This is supposed to give you the object with the aliasing as shown, but every Rails console I try this in just gives me a nil record. i.e. `t = Tool.select("serial as my_serial").where(id: 38)
  Tool Load (1.3ms)  SELECT serial as my_serial FROM "tools" WHERE "tools"."id" = 38
=> [#<Tool id: nil>]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined the two answers above to get what i needed. :)

```
  def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    @searches = []
    (@searches << @search.district_resources).flatten!

    json = @searches.to_json(:include => [:state => {:only => [:name]}] )

    def flatten_hash(h)
      new_hash = []
      h.each do |val|
        if val.is_a?(Hash)
          val["state"] = val["state"]["name"]
          val.delete("state_id")
          (new_hash << val).flatten!
        else
          new_hash << val
        end
      end
      new_hash
    end

    flattened_hash = flatten_hash(JSON.parse(json))

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      #(:include => [:state => {:only => [:name]}] )
      format.json { render :json => flattened_hash.to_json }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate it how ever you like, i.e. pass it to another variable, use a method call etc:

```
  my_json["state"] = my_json["state"]["name"]
  my_json.delete("state_id")
```

This will set `state =>` to the value of `name =>` and then delete the unwanted `state_id =>`

Answer (score 1):

I second the remark of Beartech but let's suppose that is not possible then do it like this

```
require 'json'

def flatten_hash(h)
  new_hash = {}
  h.each_pair do |key, val|
    if val.is_a?(Hash)
      new_hash[key] = val.values.join(',')
    else
      new_hash[key] = val
    end
  end
  new_hash
end

json = '{"id":4,"state_id":5,"name":"School Liason Officer","created_at":"2014-10-16T03:13:00.000Z", "updated_at":"2014-10-16T03:13:00.000Z","state":{"name":"California"}}'
flattened_hash = flatten_hash(JSON.parse(json).to_hash)
flattened_hash.delete("state_id")
```

gives

```
{"id"=>4, "name"=>"School Liason Officer", "created_at"=>"2014-10-16T03:13:00.000Z", "updated_at"=>"2014-10-16T03:13:00.000Z", "state"=>"California"}
```

Comment: My current output is an array of hashes. Therefore i keep getting this error  (undefined method `to_hash' for #<Array:0x007f8d6ffa5f38>):

Comment: can't find that in your question, but then don't use to_hash since it's allready a hash, just flatten it while you enumerate the array